# Loading a page with non-default constructor into Frame

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to use a `frame` to host different type of xaml pages.  The user will select the page to be loaded.
I want to load a page with a non-default constructor into the Frame.
I found the following code on MSDN:

```
void hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the page to navigate to
    PageWithNonDefaultConstructor page = new PageWithNonDefaultConstructor("Hello!");

    // Navigate to the page, using the NavigationService
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
}
```

The above code replaces the currently displayed page, but I want it to load into a specific frame element on the current page.

```
<Frame Source="Default.xaml" />
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem using the Content of Frame instead of Source.

```
//xaml
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Something"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click"/>
        <Frame Content="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>

//codebehinde
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Instantiate the page to navigate to
    Page1 page = new Page1("Hello!");
    this.DataContext = page;
}
```